# How do you save a scikit-image PiecewiseAffineTransform?

Tags: python, scikit-image

I am using `scikit-image` to distort image with `skimage.transform.PiecewiseAffineTransform`.

I have run this very long `skimage.transform.estimate_transform`, now I have a `PiecewiseAffineTransform` object.

How can I save it on the disk to get it back later?

Comment: Try [Pickle](https://pythonexamples.org/python-pickle-class-object/)

Comment: Yeah, it worked (: